# Sending '__autoreleasing id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *'

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, autorelease

```
Sending '__autoreleasing id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id *' changes retain/release properties of pointer
```

Can any one help me resolving this problem!

Answer (score 5):

I'm just getting up to speed on ARC myself, but I've had the same error so perhaps I can try to help with this.

`__unsafe_unretained` is used when you want to support iOS 4+. For iOS 5.0+ `__weak` should be used. The difference being that the `__weak` pointer is zeroed. Meaning, when nothing else has a reference to the object and it's deallocated, the `__weak` pointer will be set to nil. So if you do reference it, you won't get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crash.

Like anything else, such as object type, and qualifiers, for Objective-C objects in ARC you now have to specify the lifetime. That's so that ARC knows how to synthesize the retain/release calls.

If you don't specify anything the default will be `__strong`.

These lifetime specifiers have to match.

In your case, you are assigning one pointer that is `__unsafe_unretained` to another that is `__strong`.

To resolve, change the receiving pointer to also be `__unsafe_unretained`. This might mean adding the lifetime specifier to the method signature. For example:

```
- (void)myMethod:(__unsafe_unretained NSString *)aString
{    
}
```

Don't forget that `__unsafe_unretained` is as it's namesake describes. It's not safe and it's not retained! So you'd better be retaining that object safely somewhere else, and not referring to it in a method like this after it has been released. You would just use this for weak references in delegates in for example a parent/child relationships. For everything else, specifically normal Objective-C ivars you should be using `__strong`.